# Is it appropriate to use id-s in MongoDb subdocuments?

Tags: c#, nosql, mongodb

I'm currently familiarizing myself with NoSQL by building a simple web application using MongoDb with the official C# driver. If i have understood the NoSQL concept correctly, then only the aggregate root document should have an id and the child collections are without identity.

For example in C# code i would have the following 2 Poco-s:

```
public class User
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("pets")]
    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; } 
}

public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How would i solve a case, where i want to have separate CRUD views for pets? With a relational database i would do this by having the pet id in the query string, with NoSQL i'm not sure.

This question arose from when i tried to add an Id field to the "Pet" subdocument. Instead of an id for pet, an object named "_csharpnull" was added to the database instead.

For example if i do this:

```
public class User
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("pets")]
    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; } 
}

public class Pet
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then this document is inserted into the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5643a1f9766bcf0fc0b26f14"),
    "pets" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_csharpnull" : true
            },
            "Name" : "T-Rex"
        }
    ]
}
```

When my expected behavior would be something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5643a1f9766bcf0fc0b26f14"),
    "pets" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56439adc766bcf49a0639992"),
            "Name" : "T-Rex"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It feels like you have two different questions here: 1) Should my Pets have ids? and 2) Why am I seeing this _csharpnull thing? The first one is on-topic here (though we might need more details), while the second is more of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Ixrec I have only one question. The _csharpnull thing is just an example of confirming my doubts, as i'm not experienced with NoSQL.

Comment: Why would you ever put anything in a data store without an ID of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

While I am not aware of a particular standard that says yes or no, in my experience this can and should in many cases be done.

The moment you want to be able to handle a `Pet` on it's own in various operations you need an ID. The simplest way in MongoDB is to just give it an ObjectID.

But I also have run into cases where this was not needed, such as when you have a sub document which always appears together with it's main document.

While I am not familiar with C# particularly, what you are trying to do definitely works in Java. Just make sure you actually initialize the ObjectID manually. While MongoDB creates object IDs for you on the top level documents of a collection it will not do the same for child documents.

Answer (score 0):

> If i have understood the NoSQL concept correctly, then only the
>   aggregate root document should have an id and the child collections
>   are without identity.

I am not sure relational or even NoSQL document-oriented databases goes perfectly well with [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) in all cases.

Will your document have an object id /primary key or not should be considered an implementation detail (though if you are not careful, it **WILL** affect your modelling process).

What is more important is the way you treat that particular document. Do you access it from outside of aggregate root boundaries by id? If you delete it and recreate the complete same object, but with different id will it affect your application logic somehow? Etc.

I think it would be better to have value object without ids so that there would be no temptation for you to address them  using ids. But if on some reason you should have, consider it an implementation detail and concentrate on following the domain logic first.